# Influxdb Unauthorized 401 with python insert data

Tags: influxdb

I have see many article about this issue, but it all can not solve my problem.
I use python to insert data which code is the offical offer.

```
from datetime import datetime

from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

# You can generate an API token from the "API Tokens Tab" in the UI
token = "myToken"
org = "myOrg"
bucket = "Test"

with InfluxDBClient(url="http://127.0.0.1:8086", token=token, org=org) as client:
```

but it seem st wrong with my influxdb.conf?

```
influxdb_client.rest.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-Influxdb-Build': 'OSS', 'X-Influxdb-Version': '2.1.1', 'X-Platform-Error-Code': 'unauthorized', 'Date': 'Mon, 07 Mar 2022 09:20:36 GMT', 'Content-Length': '55'})
HTTP response body: {"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"}
```

Comment: Did you go into the influxdb UI and generate an API token, and give that API token the proper permissions, ?

Comment: @nos Yes, I have already solve this problem, you are right